# After the colon, should I use “to speak” and then “to be” or just the bare infinitives?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives

After the colon, should I use “to speak” and then “to be” or just the bare infinitives in the following sentence:

> *Now, you can see what the two necessary conditions were in order to stay here: **(to) respect**  these old men and **(to) be** an honest
> man.*

Comment: There's no semicolon; it's a colon, followed by conjoined infinitive phrases. You can use either both bare infinitives, both with _to_, or the first one with _to_ and the second one bare. Not the opposite arrangement, however - conjunction reduction deletes only the second _to_, not the first.

Comment: I am correcting my typo. Thank you.